# Powerquery - How to pick the lower value from a column, when the value is to be compared against another value from a different row

Tags: powerquery

Hi. I have the following table.
[image]

I want an output that will compare the numbers in the total price column with a similar index number and return the lowest number. Hence for above table, the expected output will be;

Index | Total Price |
------ |-------------|
2        |    40,664.95|
------ |-------------|
9        |    29,706.29  |
------ |-------------|
25      |    1,076.36  |
------ |-------------|
32      |    4,122.49  |
------ |-------------|
39        |    2,759.07  |

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merely GroupBy Index and use the Min for the operation:

[image]